# Automating crystal report - need to run for the last week

Tags: crystal-reports, date-range

I have a crystal report I run weekly and manually update the dates to pull the last 7 days (not including today).  I've tried to use 'in last7days' and/or {date} >= minimum(lastfullweek) + 1
and {date} <= maximum(lastfullweek) + 1.  I can't get this query to run - I get an error saying a string is required here.  My date format is yyyy-mm-dd.  I need to update this report to run automatically - I don't want to run the report by manually updating the date range every week.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably comparing a string to a date. Check the data types of the elements in your expression. Most likely your {date} column is a string rather than a date.

See if you can convert it to a date (e.g. the cDate() function).

Answer (score 0):

Try [R-Tag Community Edition](http://r-tag.com/Pages/CommunityEdition.aspx). It is free and has the option to set the dates and other values outside the report so you don't have to hardcode them inside the report.